# Function to get point on line where two points are known

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given two points:

```
const point1 = {x: 100, y: 0.95}
const point2 = {x: 75, y: 1.05}
```

I need to know the value of y when x equals some arbitrary value.

Please assume a linear relationship exists.

For example, what is y when x is 80? what is y when x is 70?

Is there a function that I could use for this?

Currently I've been confused by mathematical explanations and would ideally like a JavaScript or jQuery function that, when given an arbitrary x value returns the y value.

Comment: something like :- {75,1.05},{50,1.15},{25,1.25}{0,1.35}{90,0.99}

Comment: All answers are correct so +1 to every-one.As well as to question to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, the `gradient` of a line is the amount `y` increases for every unit `x` increases. E.g. if `y` goes up 5 for every 2 `x` goes up, the line is said to have a gradient of 2.5.

The gradient can be calculated from 2 points like so:

```
var gradient = (point2.y - point1.y) / (point2.x - point1.x);
```

The intercept of a line is the `y` value it crosses the `y` axis at. It can be calculated from 1 point like so:

```
var intercept = point1.y - (gradient * point1.x);
```

The `y` value for any `x` value can then be calculated:

```
var x = 10;
var y = gradient * x + intercept;
```

A function which combines these things might look like:

```
function yFromX(point1, point2, x) {
  var gradient = (point2.y - point1.y) / (point2.x - point1.x);
  var intercept = point1.y - (gradient * point1.x);
  return gradient * x + intercept;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer +1 but there is a typo in your code ... you have ... point1.y=x ... should be ... point1.x ... very clear code, nice use of variable names ... many thx ... PS if you fix this I will accept this answer

Answer (score 4):

```
const point1 = {x: 100, y: 0.95}
const point2 = {x: 75, y: 1.05}

function getY (x) {
    var gradient = (point1.y - point2.y)/(point1.x - point2.x);
    return point1.y + gradient * (x - point1.x);
}

alert(getY(90));
```

Answer (score 3):

calculate m(gradient) and c(offset) using the two points given and then use these points to calculate y for any x.

```js
const point1 = {x: 100, y: 0.95}
const point2 = {x: 75, y: 1.05}

var m = (point1.y - point2.y) / (point1.x - point2.x);   // gradient formula 
var c = point1.y - m*point1.x;        // offset formula

function findY(x){
  return m*x + c;
}

console.log(findY(80));
console.log(findY(70));
```